# require_once(PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, phpexcel, silverstripe

I am trying to include PHPExcel to a Silverstripe 3 site to export excel sheets. Right now I am just trying to test, but I get this error when trying to do it:

> [Warning] require_once(/sitename/mysite/AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Thing is I know this file exists since I copied it over myself and have rechecked the path over and over. So I decided "well check if the file exists" using this code:

```
    if(!file_exists(Director::baseURL().'mysite/AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php')) {
        echo 'sdf';exit;
}
```

The path is correct (that is where it is saved) according to the error, but- file does not exist. I am also requiring the file in the same way, with no luck

```
require_once Director::baseURL().'mysite/AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
```

I have tried everything-checking file permissions, referencing parent folders using `../../`, calling it directly like `AddOns/PHPExcel`, moving it to this new AddOns folder (first tried placing the PHPExcel classes on the root and discovered that Silverstripe doesn't read it then :) )

I know I am doing something wrong but for the life of me I cannot see what. Please help

Thanks

Comment: can you echo Director::baseURL().'mysite/AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php'  and to to that link? does it open the right file?

Comment: I think that `Director::baseURL()` is referring to the url in the browser, no for the path where the project is.

Comment: @JeffreyTroost did the echo and decided to try a redirect as well just in case - it points to the correct file but gives me a 403 Forbidden error. Gave full control to everyone (it is local so) and it did the same

Comment: @VasilShaddix what do you suggest using then?

Comment: @CasperBritz try including relative from the file like so: `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');` -- but be sure to modify to represent your file structure

Comment: @JanneKlouman I have so much to learn. That works perfectly! Thanks! now a Stackoverflow question- should i make the answer and mark it or must you?(still noobish here)

Comment: @CasperBritz No problem! Intended use is I make the answer and you can mark it. Welcome to SO and welcome to SilverStripe :-)

Comment: There's now a couple of better answers with valuable insight, consider changing the accepted answer @CasperBritz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BASE_PATH` is the best way to access the web root folder.

```
require_once(BASE_PATH . '/AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
```

Also this is only an issue if you are not using composer, to solve this issue in the correct way you should [use composer](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/getting_started/composer/).

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using [composer](http://getcomposer.org) to include the PHPExcel class, this will avoid the need to manually `require` the class and will help you with dependency management.

```
composer require phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Comment: Will definately start using this in the future then

Comment: Note that that package is now deprecated; the author suggests using `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out `Director::baseURL()` will return the URL rather than the filepath.

Instead require relative to the <s>file</s> web root like so:

`require_once(BASE_PATH . '/AddOns/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');`

As pointed out by both Dan and Barry in the other answers, it's preferable to use composer for dependency management.

Comment: The `BASE_PATH` constant is the best way to do this

Comment: Ah, thanks! That makes sense. Updated my answer to reflect this. Perhaps @CasperBritz should consider changing the accepted answer.